# Optimization of conditions applying

Tags: performance-tuning, filtering, conditional, sow-reap

Let we have some data generator, e.g. lazy tuples or permutations.
I need to select data by some conditions `cond1, cond2, …,` up to 5-6 conditions.
All of them need enough calculations; some discard 50% of data, some 20% etc.

Firstly I wrote something like this:

```
Reap[
    …
    yield = …;
    If[cond1&&cond2&&cond3&&...,
          Sow[yield]
     ];
…
]
```

But thinking like a pupil, I wrote this:

```
Reap[
    …
    yield = …;
    If[cond1,
          If[cond2,
                If[cond3,
              ….
               Sow[yield]
                 ]]];
…
]
```

And doing so, I estimated that the first condition discards 50% data, second 30%, third 10% etc. Data is big enough, by the way.
This trick made all process *faster over 5-6 times.*

But the code with nested `If` looks so ridiculous so I'm shy to post it on Codegolf or somewhere ((

So is there more code-styled way to avoid all-together conditions calculations?

Comment: Try:  `If[cond1 && cond2 && cond3,..`

Comment: @DanielHuber This is slow, if conditions need enough calculations. With `&&`  all of them are calculated every time

Comment: `Pick[list, cond1/@list] // Pick[#, cond2/@#] // Pick[#, cond3/@#] ...`

Comment: @Syed, yes for lists it's good, but what about sequentially generated data? List will be very huge

Comment: I think you will get a more concrete answer, when you include a minimal example as well as indicate the size of the lists. Tasks involving permutations become unmanageable quickly, but there might be useful alternative strategies for your specific problem.

Comment: @lesobrod You are wrong, "&&" is preemptive. As soon as one condition is wrong, it returns.

Comment: @DanielHuber  But why it slower 5-6 times than nested `if` with the same conditions and calculations?